# Error using mex LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_60.lib'

Tags: matlab, boost, linker, mex

I wrote a simple cpp program (1 source file) in VS2015 that uses some boost libraries. The program compiles and runs just fine in VS. I am trying to create a mex file in Matlab so that I can run the program from there. Here is the mex command I use:

```
mex -IC:\Users\Engineer\Documents\boost_1_60_0 Source.cpp
```

I then get the following error:

Error using mex
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
'libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_60.lib'

I know this file exists and I already tried building boost with runtime static linking. I've verified that mex is using VS2015 c++ compiler. Is there something else I should be doing here? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `-l` instead of `-I` to include the folder as a library folder, not as a header folder.

Comment: @JaBe that made it worse :) with -l mex looked for C:\Users\Engineer\Documents\boost_1_60_0.lib which is nonsense

Comment: @JaBe with -L it got farther but couldn't another file called config.hpp I've had little luck with any of the input options so far

Comment: `-I` tells the compiler where the header files are, so you could add the folder of your `config.hpp`.

Comment: you need to specify both headers and libs location, something like: `mex -I"C:\path\to\include" Source.cpp -L"C:\path\to\libs" -lmylib`